# how to add a new phtml file into another file

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template, xml, phtml

I added like that in page.xml

```
<block type="page/html_banner" name="banner" as="banner" template="page/html/banner.phtml">
</block>
```

but didn't get the template.

please any one suggest me.

Comment: can you explain clearly.how you want

Comment: i want to include a new phtml file like header I mean my file is banner.phtml

Comment: <block type="page/html_banner" name="banner" as="banner" template="page/html/banner.phtml"><block type="page/html_banner" name="header" as="header" template="page/html/header.phtml">
</block>
</block> in banner.phtml you can call $this->getChildHtml(header);

Comment: I added in page.xml

Comment: By using the above code you can call header.phtml in banner.phtml

Comment: where I paste that code in page.xml

Comment: inside banner.phtml you want to access other file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<block type="page/html_banner" name="banner" as="banner" template="page/html/banner.phtml">

  <block type="page/html_banner" name="custom" as="custom" template="page/html/custom.phtml"> 
   </block>
```

In banner.phtml you can call `$this->getChildHtml('custom');` to access custom.phtml inside banner.phtml

(or)

Try the below code inside banner.phtml,

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_banner')->setTemplate('page/html/custom.phtml')->toHtml();
```